# Selected element won't change in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, d3.js

This snippet is a slightly modified version of the example http://bl.ocks.org/4063550 of a Reingold-Tilford Tree.  Everything is similar, except I have slightly changed the code where one appends the text to a node.  I want to attach an id to each node text so that I can later tweak the text a bit so the graph is more readable.

Here I add the id's and slightly tweak the rotation of the entire diagram. My changes are enclosed with the **.

```
node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  **.attr("id", function(d,i) {return "n" + i;})**
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "**rotate(10)**translate(8)" :"**rotate(199)**translate(-8)"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});
```

Right after the example code with the above being the only changes, I want to put the following line, for example, into the same script.

```
d3.select("#n1").text("test");
```

When I load the page it's not changing the text at node id = "n1"!  If I put exactly that same line into the console with Firebug, it changes the n1 node's text as desired.

After browsing countless tutorials and the like, I think that I don't understand something fundamental about how this stuff works, any advice would be appreciated!

Edit:  Here is the complete html file as requested!  It is verbatim the example I linked above, with the only exceptions being what I described above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var diameter = 960;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

d3.json("thesis.json", function(error, root) {
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".25em")
      .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "n" + i;})
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "rotate(10)translate(8)" : "rotate(199)translate(-8)"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter  + "px");

d3.select("#n1").text("test");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete code? Where exactly are you calling the line to change the text? Outside the `d3.json` block that draws the main graph by any chance?

Comment: There is the complete code!  I am trying to change the text outside of the d3.json call.  I'm not experienced at this (obviously!) and my thinking was to first just create the diagram, then afterwards modify the text.

Comment: Maybe once I learn what the issue is I can change the title of the post to make it less generic and more useful for others.

Comment: Just to be clear, the diagram does load correctly, and the text elements do appear to have their id's labeled correctly, I just can't use that last line to modify a text element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `d3.json` makes an asynchronous call. That is, the code *within* that block is only executed when the network call returns with the JSON data. The code *after* the block is executed immediately though. So, you are trying to modify an element that does not exist yet.

The solution is to move the code that modifies the graph inside the `d3.json` block, or into a function that is called inside that block.

Comment: Okay thanks!  Yeah, when I realized that the last line worked fine from the Firebug console I started to think that somehow the diagram wasn't ready yet.  Although I'm a total noob and didn't know how to correctly articulate that like you just did.  Thanks!